# obiee 11g using catalog manager to extract layout and views of an analyse

Tags: obiee

i am using obiee 11g and I want to extract some documentation out of the catalog manager. I explain. I have some analyse with some views I added like for example a title and a static text. I renamed those views to documentation. Now I want to extract for each analyse those two views. I thought I could do that with the catalog manager and the tool>extract report like I saw some examples [here](https://shivabizint.wordpress.com/2013/05/08/obiee-impact-analysis-what-if-i-delete-a-column-from-rpd-what-are-the-reports-that-are-being-affected-part-1/).

The problem is that I don't find how I can extract the view or compound layout with the catalog manager.

Answer (score -2):

You can archive and unarchive  the analysses and dashboards etc..

And unarchive to anywhere or any server you have the same Model ...

Go to catalog, select your analysis, archive , and unarchive ll be at down left corner:
[image]

Comment: That's not what the OP is asking for